# palindromic numbers

Tags: ruby

Here is working code:

```
p = (10..14).map { |a|
  (a..14).map { |b|
    a * b
  }
flatten.select { |p|
  p.to_s == p.to_s.reverse
}
```

But I want to keep the information about 'a' and 'b' which produced 'a * b':

```
p = (10..14).map { |a|
  (a..14).map { |b|
    [a, b, a * b, '=']
  }
}.select { |v|
  v[2].to_s == v[2].to_s.reverse
}

puts p
```

This code print not palindromic number. I guess that reason is a Array flatten. How do I need to change code to get palindromic number?

Comment: Isn't every palindromic integer the same as the integer itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to flatten only one level, so use `flatten(1)` instead.

```
(10..14).map { |a|
  (a..14).map { |b|
    [a, b, a * b, '=']
  }
}.flatten(1).select { |v|
  v[2].to_s == v[2].to_s.reverse
}
```

Alternatively, replace your outer `map` by [`flat_map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001492):

```
(10..14).flat_map { |a|
  (a..14).map { |b|
    [a, b, a * b, '=']
  }
}.select { |v|
  v[2].to_s == v[2].to_s.reverse
}
```

*Note*: `flatten` takes an argument since Ruby 1.8.7. [`flat_map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001492) is new to Ruby 1.9.2. Make sure you have the right version, or [`require "backports/1.9.2/enumerable/flat_map"`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) or `require "backports/1.8.7/array/flatten"`.

Comment: Link to flat_map RDoc: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001492

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: I edited my answer (and feel free to do that in the future!) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since you don't call `flatten` in the second version, the array is too nested and the select doesn't work because `v` is a row of elements, not a single elements. However if you'd just call `flatten` like in the first version, the resulting array would be too flat.

There are multiple ways to solve this:

1. In 1.9.2 you can replace the outer call to ´map`with`flat_map`which works like`map`, but automatically produces a flat array.
2. In 1.8.7+ you can call `flatten(1)` instead of `flatten`, which will flatten the array by exactly one level of nesting, resulting in the structure you want.
3. Instead of an array you could define a class to represent a number, which avoids the problem of accidentally flattening the inner arrays lets you access the properties of the number more meaningfully.

Option 3 could look like this:

```
Product = Struct.new(:factor1, :factor2) do
  def product
    factor1 * factor2
  end

  def to_s
    "#{factor1} * #{factor2} = #{product}"
  end
end

products = (10..14).map { |a|
  (a..14).map { |b|
    Product.new(a,b)
  }
}.flatten.select { |prod|
  prod.product.to_s == prod.product.to_s.reverse
}

puts products
```

Answer (score 1):

```
palindromes = []

(10..14).each do |a|
  (a..14).each do |b|
    p = (a * b).to_s
    palindromes << [a,b] if p == p.reverse
  end
end

puts palindromes.join(',')

wesbailey@feynman:~/code_katas> ruby palindrome.rb 
11,11
```